# useEffect with function that update the state as dependency leads to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, use-effect, use-state

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-breeze-d260k

#### The code:

- This is a simple auth app
- When you click `Login`, the accessToken is exchanged and stored in memory while the refreshToken is stored in localStorage.
- While the accessToken is valid (here a timestamp), the Home page shows the protected content
- At every page reload (i.e App initialization), the refreshToken is sent to the server and if it is valid, a new accessToken is exchanged.

#### The problem:

- To refresh the token on App initialization, I have an `onRefreshToken()` function in a useEffect to be executed once (I wanted to pass an empty array as dependency but typescript/eslint complains and suggest that `onRefreshToken()` should be the dependency. I admit that I don't understand why this is recommended to have always a dependency when you want the effect to be executed once).
- Once the token is renewed, I store the accessToken and the user profile in their respective context.
- Infinite re-render loop begins. On my local server, this is due to `setProfile()` and not `setAccessToken()`. However I don't understand why.

#### Side note

The above issue is the main issue of this post but on a side note, the login/logout process don't sync between tabs so if you have any idea why, I would be happy to hear your advice on this point as well.

Happy new year

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this would be to check to see if you have an access token and only refresh it if you need to:

```
export default function App() {
  const { accessToken } = useAuthContext();
  const { onRefreshToken, onSyncLogin, onSyncLogout } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const refresh = async () => {
      await onRefreshToken();
    };
    !accessToken && refresh();
  }, [onRefreshToken, accessToken]);
```